# Operations with the value of worksheetfunction in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, function, vba, matrix

I have two functions, the first one works, the code of the second one is almost the same of the first one but at the end tries to make some arithmetic operations with the final result. The seconde one doesn't work. The codes are the following:

```
        Public Function li(a As Double, b As Double) As Variant
        Dim mat(1 To 1, 1 To 3) As Variant
        Dim re As Variant

        Dim imat(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Variant

        imat(1, 1) = 0.7409287
        imat(1, 2) = -0.2849031
        imat(1, 3) = 0.00002678114
        imat(2, 1) = -0.2849031
        imat(2, 2) = 0.1108151
        imat(2, 3) = 0.00000774442
        imat(3, 1) = -0.00002678114
        imat(3, 2) = 0.00000774442
        imat(3, 3) = 0.000000009373992

        mat(1, 1) = 1
        mat(1, 2) = a ^ 0.25
        mat(1, 3) = b ^ 2

        re = WorksheetFunction.MMult(WorksheetFunction.MMult(mat, imat), WorksheetFunction.Transpose(mat))


        li = re

        End Function

'here the second function starts

        Public Function eli(a As Double, b As Double) As Variant
        Dim mat(1 To 1, 1 To 3) As Variant
        Dim re As Variant

        Dim imat(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Variant

        imat(1, 1) = 0.7409287
        imat(1, 2) = -0.2849031
        imat(1, 3) = 0.00002678114
        imat(2, 1) = -0.2849031
        imat(2, 2) = 0.1108151
        imat(2, 3) = 0.00000774442
        imat(3, 1) = -0.00002678114
        imat(3, 2) = 0.00000774442
        imat(3, 3) = 0.000000009373992

        mat(1, 1) = 1
        mat(1, 2) = a ^ 0.25
        mat(1, 3) = b ^ 2

        re = WorksheetFunction.MMult(WorksheetFunction.MMult(mat, imat), WorksheetFunction.Transpose(mat))



        eli = 1.96 * 126.948551122683 * (re + 1) ^ 0.5

        End Function
```

I guess the problem in the second one is because `re` is the value of a `worksheetfunction`. So, How Can I fix that?

Comment: **NB** Next time please describe what the problem is, rather than simply saying it "doesn't work", indicate what error message is raised and on which line it is raised.  (If there is not an error message, then describe how the results differ from what you expect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging this you would get a mismatch error on the return statement.

`eli = 1.96 * 126.948551122683 * (re + 1) ^ 0.5`

Look in the Locals window and you'll see that `re` is a variant array, dimensioned 1 to 1.

[image]

An array doesn't have a default value property, so the solution is to refer to the array index:

`eli = 1.96 * 126.948551122683 * (re(1) + 1) ^ 0.5`

See [THIS LINK](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) for some helpful hints on how to debug your own code like this.  Cheers.